# 500 Internal server error in kunena

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, fatal-error

I am using Joomla 1.5.2 and the [Kunena Forum](http://kunena.org) Component,
When I click on the Kunena forum in the back end I get a 500 Internal server error. The full error is as shown below.

```
  Fatal Error: require_once() [function.require]: 
    Failed opening required '/home/example/public_html/administrator/components/com_kunena/install/version.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in components/com_kunena/admin.kunena.php on line 46
```

The error was detected in the Kunena Component.

Could anyone help me to resolve?

Comment: I assume you are using the latest version of Kunena (2.0.1). You should also be using the latest version of Joomla 1.5 (1.5.26). We you upgrading your Kunena or installing from fresh? what version of PHP are you using. Please provide more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happened because of not proper installing. You may uninstall the component and install it again,. It may solves your problem.